# SystemVerilog introduces logic, but why?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Is there any area in SystemVerilog where I can use **logic** but not **reg**?

I looked a lot for an answer to this question, but there isn't one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 6.11.2 *2-state (two-value) and 4-state (four-value) data types*:

> The keyword **reg** does not always accurately describe user intent, as it
> could be perceived to imply a hardware register. The keyword **logic** is
> a more descriptive term. **logic** and **reg** denote the same type.

Since they denote the same type, they should be interchangeable.